# How to copy state from my react-native app to my AWS Kinesis Firehose stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amazon-kinesis-firehose

With the necessary imports & configuration it is quite simple to use Storage.put from aws amplify to record text in this.state.appended to S3 mybucket using a function...

```
doComprehend = () => {
     Storage.put('apptext.txt', this.state.appended)
    .then (result => {
      console.log('result: ', result)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));
}
```

How would I **alter this function** so that it sends the text in this.state.appended to an **AWS Firehose stream** instead?

Context of my problem: my RN app sends text to an aws bucket as the apptext.txt file, that triggers a lambda that calls aws comprehend and comprehend medical and it all works but I can't append the results of the lambda to the apptext.txt file inside the S3 bucket because that's not possible...

I want to change it so that the text I'm interested in is first put into a firehose stream, transformed there by the lambda and then saved to the S3 bucket.

I've looked at the Amplify docs. I've looked at aws-sdk-js. I tried npm firehoser. I can't figure out how to do it.